# Hockeyapp distribution with daily build

Tags: android, hockeyapp

I have developed an android application and it has been deployed on the server side, and apk file generated and I want to automate the steps with hockeyapp distribution. When the .apk has been built, I want to send it to the testers.

My question is how hockeyapp could be automated with daily build? Is there any guideline or tutorial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick googling for a 'gradle hockeyapp plugin' brought up [this](https://github.com/x2on/gradle-hockeyapp-plugin). 
Another option (imho preferred one) is to have a build server like [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/) do your builds (usually connected to your git or other vcs), there's plugins for those too that will upload builds to hockeyapp automatically.